# software to proxy/gateway all traffic

Tags: vpn, proxy, gateway

My friend is in a country where facebook is blocked, but he wants to use facebook api services that is blocked.  He can't use proxy because there's no way to configure the api lib for accessing facebook api to use a proxy.  so other than setting up a vpn hosted outside of China, is there any other way to get around?  gateway?  how?
looking for a Linux-based solution.

Answer (score 4):

Why disclaim the use of a VPN?  If you're thinking "VPN == IPSec", you're limiting your world view significantly.  OpenVPN is incredibly simple to setup and run, takes very few resources, and runs on the big three OSes (although it's most at home on Linux).  It's also got the ability to run over an HTTPS proxy (including an option to make it issue the necessary `CONNECT` command, so if you have the VPN server listening on 443/tcp instead of the default (1194/udp), you can get a VPN even when you're behind a very, very limiting firewall.

Comment: Agreed.  VPN is probably the best solution.

You can signup for a VPN membership at http://sdf1.org/index.cgi?vpn

SDF is a public access Unix system that has an active community of members.  You should also be able to setup and SSL tunnel through an account here as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [openvpn](http://openvpn.net) or [socks / port forwarding over ssh](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/449).

remote endpoint would need to be hosted in so called free world - that is outside great firewall of oppressive country.